# gae bigquery works from dev_appserver but credential errors during tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I have a gae app and it has a view that does this:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
# Grab the application's default credentials from the environment.
oCredentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
# Construct the service object for interacting with the BigQuery API.
oBigQuerySerivice = build('bigquery', 'v2', credentials=oCredentials)

oTables = oBigQuerySerivice.tables()
d = oTables.list(projectId=PROJECT,datasetId=DATASET).execute()
```

And it works just great

Now I want to run the same code in my unit tests, the same virtualenv is activated. It refers to the same dataset, the same project and the same json service key file. i would expect the result to be the same. But alas:

```
HttpError: <HttpError 401 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/projectwaxed/datasets/bi_audit_dev/tables?alt=json returned "Invalid Credentials">
```

My question is: How am I supposed to test that my code is doing valid big query stuff? The docs are all over the place and I'm just not finding answers

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to poke at this, not sure how helpful it will be. Apologies. Is your app not authenticating with GAE in this instance or just big query?

I struggled against a lot of the auth issues dealing with BT and App Engine. I'm trying to dig up my notes from when I dealt with it. The Google BigQuery analytics book is pretty solid if you are able to purchase it, but some of the Auth stuff is already out of date.

If you type printenv (unix), do you see the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS path declared? I had issues where my env vars weren't surviving new vm instances.

BTW, I used this youtube video for the oauth2 walkthrough - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HoUdWBzUZ-M